# Formulation of the least-squares parameter estimation problem

Tags: optimization, ode, least-squares

I have a system of 10 ordinary differential equations of the form,

$$\frac{dy_1}{dt} = f1(V1,k1,y1,y2)\\
\vdots \\
\frac{dy_{10}}{dt} = f_{10}(V_{10},k_{10},y_{9},y_{10})
$$

I want to estimate the parameters $V_1 ,V_6,V_7,V_{10}$ using a  global fit.

From the approaches suggested in the literature, I understand least-squares error minimization is commonly used. However, I'm not able to understand how optimization problem is actually formulated.

Cost function = $\Sigma_{i=1}^{10} (y_i^\text{experiment} - y_i^\text{model})^2$

Where, $y_i^\text{experiment}$ is the steady-state value obtained from experiments and not the time series data of $y_i$.
Could someone explain how $y_i^\text{model}$ is expressed in terms of the parameters that are to be estimated?

Is is differential equation,(say)
$\frac{dy_1}{dt} = f1(V1,k1,y1,y2)$

expanded using Taylor polynomial to find $y_1^\text{model}$?

Could someone provide an example?

Comment: Typically it's necessary to use a numerical method (e.g. a Runge-Kutta method) to solve the ODE initial value problem.  Derivatives of the solution with respect to the parameters are then computed by finite difference approximations.

Comment: In what form do you have the system of equations? Do you have dy_n/dt at several times for some initial conditions? Do you have y_n(t)?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks a lot for your response. I'm using stiff- equation solver.I'm facing challenge in understanding how the optimization problem is solved to estimate the unknown parameters

Comment: @JacobPanikulam I have multiple steady- state values of $y_1$  to $y_{10}$ obtained from experiments

Comment: You might find following [link](https://cs.stanford.edu/~ambrad/adjoint_tutorial.pdf) useful. The way you state the problem is a classical optimization problem subject to a ODE as constraint. There are two ways of solving this, the forward approach Brian Borchers mentioned or the adjoint method linked here.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the ODE as a constraint between the parameters $V$ and the observed variable $y$.
To enforce constraints in optimization problems, you can introduce a Lagrange multiplier, which we'll call $\lambda$.
In that case, the Lagrangian for your problem is

$$L(y, \lambda, V) = \sum_i|y(t_i) - y_i^\text{experiment}|^2 + \int_0^T\lambda\cdot (\dot y - f(y, V))dt.$$

You'll then seek an extremum of the Lagrangian.
A good understanding of variational calculus is going to be really essential from here on out.
If that subject is new to you, [Weinstock's book](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0486630692) is a great introduction.
The next thing you'll want to know about is the adjoint method.
Unfortunately a lot of books and references that describe the adjoint method are very confusing, but it's been discussed on this forum a handful of times, for example [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14259/understanding-the-cost-of-adjoint-method-for-pde-constrained-optimization).
Another term you might want to google is "system identification", but the wikipedia article for it isn't very informative so you may have to do some more digging.

There's a really nice Python library for numerical fitting from symbolic definitions of the models, called [symfit](https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit).
They have an example of ODE models [here](https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fitting_types.html#ode-fitting).

Comment: Excuse me for the naive question, this subject is new to me.I'll definitely read up the references suggested.  Is the adjoint method applicable for ODE's too? I saw the descriptions were based on PDE's.

Comment: No worries, everyone's naive at first! The adjoint method is applicable to ODEs as well as PDEs. It's really even more general than that -- differential operators and their inverses are just mappings between Banach spaces -- but this is a deeper rabbit hole.

Comment: as described by Daniel Shapero the right approach for these kind of problems is the "adjoint method", some gentle intriductions are: https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.336/adjoint.pdf and https://cs.stanford.edu/~ambrad/adjoint_tutorial.pdf