# Parameter estimation using fmincon

Tags: optimization, least-squares

This is a follow up to my previous question posted [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/formulation-of-the-least-squares-parameter-estimation-problem).
I am solving an optimization problem using `fmincon` in MATLAB. There are no equality constraints in my model.  I want to pass ODEs as constraint to fmincon using, non-linear constraint, nlcon argument.
The function model  contains odes

```
function dz = model(t, z, c)  
              dz(1) = ..
              dz(2) = ..
```

I'd like to ask how the ode intergrator has to be called in the place of nlcon in fmincon(@objective,p0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nlcon).

```
%p0 = Initial Value of Parameters
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
nlcon  = ode45(@(t,z)model(t,z,x), tSpan, z0); % Is this correct?
p = fmincon(@objective,p0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nlcon);
```

Since the ode function is already called in nlcon , is it required to call the function model again inside the objective function?

```
function cost = objective(c,expZ,tSpan,z0)
sol = ode45(@(t,z)model(t,z,c), tSpan, z0); % Is this step required?
ModelZ = sol(end,:)%  the solutions obtained from model at end point of tSpan
cost = ModelZ-expZ; %expZ contains steady state values of z1,z2..
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your previous question?

Comment: @nicoguaro In order to find a solution I am implementing this based on the suggestion received in the previous post